# Determine if $g$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Define $g : ℤ_3 \times ℤ_3$ by $g (a,b) = a +_3 b$ with the usual operations of $+_3$ and $\times_3$, determine if $g$ is a ring homomorphism.

I know that I need to show that $g ( a + b) = g (a) + g(b)$, and $g( a\cdot b) = g(a)\cdot g(b)$, however I am not sure how to show this. My first idea was to use the Cayley tables for the integers $0,1,2$ but I'm not sure how to set it up based on the way that g is defined. Would I just use the basic Cayley table for mod 3 and the columns would be $a$ and the rows would be $b$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use time \times to get $\times$ instead of $x$ and \cdot to get $\cdot$ instead of $*$

Comment: Write down the formula that must hold for $g$ to commute with multiplication and then look for a counterexample.

Comment: Would it be g((a,b)*(c,d))  = (a+b)*(c+d)

Comment: or would g (a,b)*(c,d) = g(ac, bd) = ac+bd???